# Torsion-free fundamental group.

Tags: algebraic-topology, terminology

Is there a name for spaces whose fundamental group has no torsion? And what, if any, are some nice properties of these spaces?

Comment: I'm not sure if they have a name, but I know of at least some sufficient conditions for a space to have torsion-free fundamental group. The theorem is normally attributed to P. A. Smith although it's difficult to find a reference. Thm: If $X$ is an aspherical topological space with the homotopy type of a finite dimensional CW-complex, then the fundamental group of $X$ is torsion-free.

Comment: Thanks. I was interested because of the conjecture that says the Whitehead group of torsion-free groups vanishes. If the conjecture holds true then the spaces you mentioned have no non-trivial h-cobordisms, which is pretty cool.